# Reconnecting on MySQL Server Has Gone Away

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo

How can I modify this class to catch exception where MySQL Server Goes Away, and reconnect?

```
<?php
class DBConn
{
private $conn;

public function __construct( $persistent = false )
{
    try
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'test', "hoollaahaoo" );
        $this->conn->exec( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
        $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
        if ( $persistent )
            $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
    }
    catch( PDOException $e )
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function getConn()
{
    return $this->conn;
}
}
```

Comment: Grab the son of a gun by the neck and bring him home. But seriously, shouldn't I be able to reconnect by re-initializing the PDO object? The key question I think is how to setup a hook to catch query and execute methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably will need to make your own class like this one

1. remove `try/except` from `__construct`
2. then connect to you db like this:

```
$conn = null;
$limit = 10;
$counter = 0;
while (true) {
  try {
    $conn = DBConn();
    break;
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $conn = null;
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == $limit)
      throw $e;
  }

}
```

**EDIT 1**:

but if you say that your server goes away.... then may be smth like this

```
protected function _connect( $persistent = false ) {
$conn = null;
$limit = 10;
$counter = 0;
while (true) {
  try {
        $this->conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'test', "hoollaahaoo" );
        $this->conn->exec( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
        $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
        if ( $persistent )
            $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
}
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $conn = null;
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == $limit)
      throw $e;
  }
}

public function __construct( $persistent = false )
{
    $this->_connect($persistent);
}
```

Comment: but isn't this catching all exceptions?? shouldn't we only catch `MySQL Server Has Gone Away` ??

Comment: @Bludream Yes I agree, first, you should only catch the PDOException (other exception types aren't our problem).  Second, I believe that the code  on PDOexceptions is set to the error code the SQL server generated.  You can check for the specific code for SQL server has gone away (you'll have to look that up yourself though).  Finally, you should sleep before attempting to reconnect because you'll just hammer the server with connection requests.  If the server is in a transient start (for example it's in the process of starting up) it might refuse connections but accept them a second later.