# php, mysql server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong, when you connect to the DB on the LINE BEFORE THE QUERY, and you still get "MySQL server has gone away"?

check this example code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM db");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$ids[] = $data[id];
}

foreach ($ids as $id) {
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.id.com/?id=$id");
if (stristr($content, "the id is ok man")) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE db SET status = 'OK' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
}
```

mysql server is gone away, i get that in the foreach loop.
BTW i need to connect in the foreachloop, because it may take along time before it finds something to update (like 1-2 minutes), and then for sure i will get mysql server has gone away.

Comment: is the both mysql connection using a same mysql server and schema?

Comment: I don't think you should connect to the database more than once for the entire script.

Comment: How do you get in your foreach loop that the connection has gone away? What is the output (error messages) of this script?

Comment: side note - I prefer to use php's PDO for all my MySQL stuff

Comment: Nute is right: only one connect is needed, outside the foreach. @Rijk: did you spot the `or die`?

Comment: the output is:

MySQL server has gone away

Comment: no, i need to connect more times. because it can take along time in the foreach loop before it finds something to update :(

Comment: You need to read some tutorials. This is not what you should do **at all**.

Comment: @kristian-rafteseth you don't need to connect more than once in any case. You may have to send dummy queries in some cases (although I don't think it's really needed).

Comment: i removed the connect in the loop. same thing happens, as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reconnecting on MySQL Server Has Gone Away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860709/reconnecting-on-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume your issue is that the script may execute for a very long time before sending the first UPDATE query.

You should check the wait_timeout value in my.cnf. You can check your wait_timeout by running the query "SHOW VARIABLES;"

You can also try to piece of code to do a reconnect:

```
if (!mysql_ping ($conn)) {
   //here is the major trick, you have to close the connection (even though its not currently working) for it to recreate properly.
   mysql_close($conn);
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
   mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
}
```

Combining with your code it would be:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM db");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if (!mysql_ping ()) {
       //here is the major trick, you have to close the connection (even though its not currently working) for it to recreate properly.
       mysql_close();
       mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
    }

    $ids[] = $data['id'];
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.id.com/?id=$id");
    if (stristr($content, "the id is ok man")) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE db SET status = 'OK' WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
}
```

Comment: same thing happens :( MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Also, I just realized, no need to loop twice?

Comment: try modified version? Also, maybe your "file_get_contents" is very slow?

Answer (score 0):

We got that error this week at work here is the official documentation from MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

> This section also covers the related Lost connection to server during query error.
>
> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to create fresh connection every time inside loop.