# MySQL server has gone away - after a mysql php loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a query over a database with over 20MM entries, that means im breaking the query into several smaller queries.

The problem is if I try to fetch the 20MM entries the page does not load and gets the notice: MySQL server has gone away, and displays a blank screen, with no title and content. However, if I fetch 5MM entries, the page does load correctly, and displays the content:

Here's my code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');
for($n=0; $n<20000000; $n=$n+500000){
    $m=500000;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_likes LIMIT ". $n .",". $m; 
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// craete arrays
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $like[$row['name']]=$like[$row['name']]+1;
    if($like[$row['name']]==375) $likes375 ++; 

}


}

// print the size
echo count($like)."<br>";
echo "375: ".$likes375;
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: If you just execute the query with out the "craete arrays" section do you still get timeouts errors?

Comment: do you really want to set_time_limit 20MM times?

Comment: if you are trying to get a count of likes wouldn't it be more efficient to do that as part of the query instead of in PHP?  Why bring all 20MM records into PHP when you can just ask MySQL for a COUNT... WHERE... ?

Comment: i dont know to do it in mysql... i need to count grouped by name and siplay only if the count is higher than 375

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reconnecting on MySQL Server Has Gone Away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860709/reconnecting-on-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes375 FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS name_count
  FROM user_likes
  GROUP BY name 
) counted
WHERE name_count > 375
```

Comment: when using this appreach i receive: Lost connection to MySQL server during quer.... the db has over 20 million rows, so probably it takes too long and the connection is closed

Comment: @DanStern try adding an index for the `name` field. If possible, use an `id` field instead of `name` for doing the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

This shows all names with a count of more than 375:

```
SELECT name
FROM user_likes
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 375
```

This is still pretty inefficient though, if there are 20M+ rows to go through; it might be better to keep this condensed data inside a smaller table.

Comment: thats the problem.. when using this appreach i receive: Lost connection to MySQL server during quer.... the db has over 20 million rows, so probably it takes too long and the connection is closed

Comment: @DanStern I suppose you could test the speed separately using a MySQL command line client, also use the EXPLAIN feature to find out how you could optimise it, though I doubt you can optimise it much in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your backing it up and your going to have to wait for it to finish and you maximum execution time for php is shorter than its going to take for the query to finish.  Suggestion is to do what you need to do in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this more efficiently on the MySQL side?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user_likes where name = '375'
```

This will be much faster than your method.  An index on name will make it faster still.

Comment: actually im not counting for name=375, im checking how many times each name appears. If appears over 375 times the counts goes one up